# connection between php scripts and html input

Tags: php, html, forms, input

```
<form id="submit-form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>dateField1</label>
    <?php
    print "<b>calendar:</b><br/>";
    $dateField1 = new dateField($format,"date1",$img);
    $dateField1->setTitles($arr_daysOfTheWeek,$arr_months,$format_title);
    $dateField1->setCssClasses($arr_cssClasses);
    print "value:" . $dateField1->makeDateField();
    ?>
    <input type="text" class="span3" name="dateField1" tabindex="2" value="    " />
</form>
```

I want to make that **value** in **php script** ... be related to the **value** of the **input** form html
I tried so many ways ,but not implemented , please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like

**PHP in HTML :**

```
<input type="text" class="span3" name="dateField1" value="<?php echo $dateField1->makeDateField();?>" />
```

Or even you can try like

**HTML in PHP :**

```
<?php echo '<input type="text" class="span3" name="dateField1" value="'. $dateField1->makeDateField().'" />';?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<form id="submit-form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>dateField1</label>
        <?php
        print "<b>calendar:</b><br/>";
        $dateField1 = new dateField($format,"date1",$img);
        $dateField1->setTitles($arr_daysOfTheWeek,$arr_months,$format_title);
        $dateField1->setCssClasses($arr_cssClasses);
        $value = $dateField1->makeDateField();
        ?>
        <input type="text" class="span3" name="dateField1" tabindex="2" value=" <?php echo $value; ?>   " />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use php inside html by starting php tags within html

```
<form id="submit-form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>dateField1</label>
    <?php
    print "<b>calendar:</b><br/>";
    $dateField1 = new dateField($format,"date1",$img);
    $dateField1->setTitles($arr_daysOfTheWeek,$arr_months,$format_title);
    $dateField1->setCssClasses($arr_cssClasses);
    print "value:" . $dateField1->makeDateField();
    ?>
    <input type="text" class="span3" name="dateField1" tabindex="2" value="<?php echo $value;?>" />
</form>
```